# Ultra simple Chrome Extension doesn't addEventListener to button onclick event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, addeventlistener

So I'm testing out creating a chrome extension. I understand that with Manifest v2 you can't have javascript in popup.html. So, I've moved the javascript to a separate file, popup.js.

I'm trying to have a simple button in a popup that calls a hello world alert, but it simply isn't working.

Moreover, Chrome's Inspect Element debugger doesn't show any error.

**popup.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script language='javascript' src='popup.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name='testForm'>
            <input type='button' id='alertButton' value='click me'>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
function myAlert(){
    alert('hello world')
}

window.onload = function(){
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        document.getElementById('alertButton').addEventListener('onclick', myAlert);
    }); 
}
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test",
  "description": "Test Extension",
  "version": "1.0",

  "icons": { 
    "48": "icon.png"
   },

  "permissions": [
    "http://*/*", 
    "https://*/*"
  ],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "This is a test",
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just remove `window.onload`:

```
function myAlert(){
    alert('hello world');
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById('alertButton').addEventListener('click', myAlert);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I also noticed that I was using "onclick" instead of "click" as the event in the event listener. Phew!

Comment: Thnx.....i was also struggling on this for 2 hours. Wasn't expecting to remove window.onload... Thnx again :)