# Trouble creating chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have successfully created an chrome extension which simply when pressed says hello word. Now when i tried to demonstrate a simple button when pressed alert comes out, doesn't work. I am thinking if it is perhaps because i use javascript inside and it has html extension.

In my folder which gets loaded in chrome has inside
a)manifest.json 
b)lab.html
c)an icon

lab.html

```
<textarea id="s" rows="2" cols="4" name="p"></textarea></br>

<button onclick="button()">Submit</button>

<script>
function button()

{
   alert("alert");
}
</script>
```

manifest

```
{
    "name": "Your Extension Name",
    "description": "Your Extension Description", 
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "38": "icon.png"
            }, 
        "default_title": "Your Extension Popup Title", 
        "default_popup": "lab.html"
    }, 
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "update_url": "http://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.google.com; object-src 'self'",
    "version": "0.1"
}
```

Comment: I need to see your manifest.json as well. Is your extension a content script, a browser action, or a page action?

Comment: Okay just did please see the edit

Comment: browser action as you can see

Comment: So, when you click the icon and the lab.html appears.... you click the button and nothing happens? Or does the lab.html not even appear?

Comment: yeah it does appear but nothing happens

Answer (score 2):

You can't execute inline JavaScript because of the [Content Security Policy](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/). The [Chrome dev docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy) have additional details.

You basically have to pull the JavaScript into a different file.

```
// script.js

function button()
{
   alert("alert");
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', button);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try reformatting your javascript:

```
function button(){
    alert('alert');
}
```

And then let's call your function as soon as the page loads, just to make sure that it is working.

So do this:

```
function button(){
    alert('alert'); 
}
button(); //call it immediately
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: still no luck, i was thinking.. is it perhaps i have my file in html extension instead of somehow create a file with a js extension because inside contains javascript not html

Comment: actually i did after seeing this post but thanks anyway [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801349/ultra-simple-chrome-extension-doesnt-addeventlistener-to-button-onclick-event)