# BrowserAction.onClicked Wait for iframe to Load

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I want to click my extension's browser action, and then have an iframe load before scrolling. 
`window.addeventlistener("load", scroll, false);` seems to be the problem right now.

I know that content scripts will make window.addEventListener work, but the content script will also inject the script all the time, and I only want to scroll when the browser action icon is clicked.

I also know that removing the `window.addeventlistener("load", scroll, false);`can make the scroll work, but then that wouldn't wait until the iframe has loaded.  Please help.

**manifest.json**

```
{
 "manifest_version": 2,

 "name": "scroll",
 "description": "scroll",
 "version": "1.0",

 "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": {
     }
 },

 "background": {
   "scripts" : ["background.js"],
   "persistent" : false
 },

 "permissions": [
   "tabs", "<all_urls>"
 ]
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "scroll.js"});
});
```

**scroll.js**

```
window.addEventListener("load", scroll, false);

function scroll (evt) {
    window.scrollTo(0, 800);
}
```

Comment: Is this related to your inquiry? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801349/ultra-simple-chrome-extension-doesnt-addeventlistener-to-button-onclick-event

Comment: Side note: the only permission you need here is [`"activeTab"`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may happen that your code executes too late (after the `load` event).

The logic should be:

- Check if the page is already loaded

  - If yes, execute immediately
  - Otherwise, attach a listener

[`document.readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) fulfills the role:

```
function scroll(evt) {
  window.scrollTo(0, 800);
}

if (document.readyState === "complete") {
  scroll();
} else {
  window.addEventListener("load", scroll, false);
}
```